# Why my machine doesn't need a password on waking up from hibernate?

Tags: ubuntu, login, hibernate

Waking my laptop up from hibernate doesn't (it should) need a password, but it does when waking up from a locked state.

I hibernate my machine (Ubuntu 15.10) by command

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

And when I turn on the machine, select Ubuntu (from multiple boot options), it straight away brings me to the screen I saw the last. No authentication check is done. This ofcourse eases my work but also makes me worry about security and privacy.

Strange thing is that, it always asks for password when system wakes up from a lock (manual or auto-timed out due to inactivity). I have lock enabled in the Brightness & Lock settings, with 5 mins screen timeout and Lock screen after: value is 'Screen turns off`.

Why doesn't my machine ask for authentication on waking up from hibernated state?

I guess pm-hibernate command uses settings different than those I see above (the default system settings). What am I missing here?

NOTE: I first asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/831811/41939) on 'askubuntu' stack exchange site, but they closed the question saying that version 15.10 is no longer supported. I don't really think it's related to the OS version, but they follow rules, while I believed askubuntu is more than an official support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The locking is done by the xscreensaver, so you are right, that it's another system.

If you want to have your system locked before going into hibernate mode, you could create a script where you call `xscreensaver-command -lock` before running `pm-hibernate`.

Comment: Thanks, I am at office and my machine is at home. I'll try your solution and update here.

Comment: I do not have `xscreensaver-command` installed on my machine. Trying in the same direction, I checked value of `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend` using `gsetting` which was set. I've also tried with `systemctl hibernate' but still the same behavior.

Comment: `/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command` should be installed if you have `xscreensaver` installed (the general screensaver package working the same on any desktop). But perhaps the best way would be to install `hibernate` (a general wrapper around several hibernation packages) and have a look in `/etc/hibernate/common.conf` which suggests several methods for locking the screen on hibernating.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent some time researching on this, trying various approaches:

- Tweaking `/etc/hibernate/common.conf` and trying to teach `/usr/share/hibernate/scriptlets.d/lock` to use `mate-screensaver-command` instead of x, gnome and the other flavours (which requires more understanding of the hibernate & pm-utils scripts than I have)
- Adding a systemd service to call `mate-screensaver -l` before sleeping (which wouldn't work without hassle since it requires detailed information about the environment to lock)

The solution that finally succeeded was the one stated by oz123 [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-lock-screen-on-suspend/16836/19): Install the `xss-lock` package and add

```
xss-lock -- mate-screensaver-command --lock
```

to the startup applications. This seems a bit odd, but at least it solves the issue in a rather easy way.

Hope the answer to this old (but alas, still current) question saves some time for someone.